# remove the directory from output in batchfile

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have the below batchfile that output ReadFile.txt file

```
cd /d "T:\EMP\SST"

for /r %%i in (T:\EMP\SST) do echo %%i >>D:\MultiThreading\ReadFile.txt
pause
```

this ReadFile.txt file output

```
T:\EMP\SST\T:\EMP\SST
T:\EMP\SST\file 11\T:\EMP\SST
T:\EMP\SST\file 12\T:\EMP\SST 
T:\EMP\SST\file 13\T:\EMP\SST
```

I want to remove the directory ouptput `T:\EMP\SST` so I want my output to be like this

```
file 11
file 12
file 13
```

how to do this

Comment: Your code and your sample output do not match! Please recheck and [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40423648/edit) your question accordingly...

Comment: @aschipfl i had to rename something in it .. but its the same , tell me if you need any explanation . all I am asking for a command or a way to remove the `directory` in the output

Comment: Thanks! So `file 11`, etc., are subdirectories, right?

Comment: @aschipfl `file 11` are name of files not folders

Comment: Hmm... `for /R` enumerates *directory trees*, not files, but you claim your output contains lines like `T:\EMP\SST\file 11\T:\EMP\SST`, which cannot be the result of your code; so please harmonise your code and sample data; otherwise the question is just confusing...

Comment: well the below answered helped me thanks you @aschipfl for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using `FOR` in a wrong way. The pattern between the parentheses isn't the start directory, it is the file/directory pattern you want to match. Here I suppose you want `*.*`

If you only want the filenames (no paths at all) you can write:

```
@echo off
for /r T:\EMP\SST %%i in (*.*) do echo %%~nxi>>D:\MultiThreading\ReadFile.txt
```

If you want the filenames + relative paths, it's slightly more complicated but doable, by enabling delayed expansion to be able to remove the path prefix + backslash:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set start_path=T:\EMP\SST
for /r %start_path% %%i in (*.*) do (
set f=%%i
echo !f:%start_path%\=!>>D:\MultiThreading\ReadFile.txt
)
```

This `FOR` command is cryptic and I have to read the help (`FOR /?`) everytime, but the fact is: everything useful is in there so I do it all the time :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you actually need `for /D` rather than `for /R` for your task (because I assume `file 11`, `file 12`, `file 13` are actually directories as they are enumerated by `for /R`):

```
for /D %%I in (T:\EMP\SST\*) do echo %%~nxI
```

---

Anyway, your `for /R` syntax is wrong; the directory you want to enumerate recursively needs to be stated immediately after the `/R` switch (if you omit it, the current directory is assumed), and you need to provide a set (that is the part in between parentheses) that constitutes a pure file name pattern only, without any (absolute or relative) paths, like `*.*`, for example, to match all files.

In your code, `for /R` enumerates the current directory. Since your set is `T:\EMP\SST` and contains no wildcards (`*`, `?`), it is just appended to the enumerated directories literally, because `for` accesses the file system only in case wildcards are encountered. That explains your weird output.